# PHP OCI auto committing when using OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT in oci_execute

Tags: php, oci8, autocommit

I am experiencing odd behavior when attempting to **NOT** auto commit inserts or updates in my php project using the `oci_*` functions.

[According to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) the insert and update queries should *not* be committed when the script ends, unless the `oci_commit` function is called:

> Using OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT mode starts or continues a transaction. Transactions are automatically rolled back when the connection is closed, or when the script ends. Explicitly call oci_commit() to commit a transaction, or oci_rollback() to abort it.
>
> When inserting or updating data, using transactions is recommended for relational data consistency and for performance reasons.
>
> If OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT mode is used for any statement including queries, and oci_commit() or oci_rollback() is not subsequently called, then OCI8 will perform a rollback at the end of the script even if no data was changed. To avoid an unnecessary rollback, many scripts do not use OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT mode for queries or PL/SQL. Be careful to ensure the appropriate transactional consistency for the application when using oci_execute() with different modes in the same script.

When I perform an INSERT query with `OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT` as second parameter in the `oci_execute` function, and afterwards call the `oci_rollback` function before the script ends, the data is not committed - as expected. But, if I do the same procedure and do not call the `oci_rollback` function (neither the `oci_commit` function) before the script ends, the data is committed. What am I missing? Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

The following code commits the insert, which is not what I expect.

```
$sqlString  = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1) VALUES ('test')";
$stid = oci_parse($dbConnection, $sqlString);
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
```

NOTE: The project is running PHP7 and OCI8.

Comment: I can't repro this using `PHP/7.0.15`, `OCI8/2.1.3`, `InstantClient/12.1.0.2.0` (all `x64` on Windows 10) inserting to an 11gR2 server. Simply adding or removing the `OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT` param causes the documented behaviour (commit or rollback) to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are not executing a subsequent DDL statement (such as CREATE TABLE) since that will trigger a commit by the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while calling procedures (I wanted to wait for all of them to be successful to commit, and if not rollback all of them).

The problem was that some people add a `COMMIT;` statement at the end of procedures, I had to remove it for it to work.